# How do I use Python's socket with GET to send https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?

Tags: python, sockets, couchdb, micropython

My goal is to send a Python GET request to a server https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 using the python socket module.  I do not want to use any of the other modules/libraries like "requests" or "urllib".  I'm just have trouble understanding where to use the /todos/1 in my code.

```
import ssl
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 443))
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
s.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")

while True:
    new = s.recv(4096)
    if not new:
      s.close()
      break
    print (new)
```

My end-goal will be to use what I learned from this exercise, to send a request to CouchDB database from a micro controller with Micropython installed, and be able to see the response headers, so that I can retrieve the returned cookie.  Micropython's urequests does not show return headers.

Comment: *" I'm just have trouble understanding where to use the /todos/1 in my code."* - essentially you are having trouble on how HTTP works. There is a standard for that for a reason and it is really recommend that you study it if you want to implement it by your own. In short: the path `/todos/1` should be where you currently have the path `/` in your request.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/urequests/urequests.py) for urequests is readily available. It would not be too difficult to modify it so that response headers are retained and made available in the returned Response object.